# starting FedoOne server

Tags: linux

I have followed the installation instructions as shown  [here](http://www.waveprotocol.org/code/installation)
to install the FedOne server,I am using openfire as the xmpp server and I have managed to run the server and the client as supposed.

After a while I thought of deploying an agent and wanted to start the FedOne server again but the run-server.sh fails complaining

`2010-09-20 12:25:30.425:WARN::FAILED SelectChannelConnector@localhost:9879: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2010-09-20 12:25:30.425:DBUG::EXCEPTION 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.ServerRpcProvider.startWebSocketServer(ServerRpcProvider.java:328)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain.run(ServerMain.java:74)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:48)
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@9300cc STOPPED
 +-ServletContextHandler@1469658@1469658/,file:/home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/FedOne/wave-protocol/war/ started
    +-ServletHandler@1304043 started
       +-[/wave]=>org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.WaveClientServlet-7654146{}
       +-[/socket]=>org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.ServerRpcProvider$WaveWebSocketServlet-33239569{bufferSize=1048576}
       +-[/static/*]=>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-21909041{}
       +-[/webclient/*]=>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet-21909041{}
       +-[/]=>org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.WaveClientServlet-9975050{}
       +-[/attachment/*]=>org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.AttachmentServlet-33355664{}

2010-09-20 12:25:30.426:WARN::FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@9300cc: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2010-09-20 12:25:30.426:DBUG::EXCEPTION 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.ServerRpcProvider.startWebSocketServer(ServerRpcProvider.java:328)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain.run(ServerMain.java:74)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:48)
Sep 20, 2010 12:25:30 PM org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.ServerRpcProvider startWebSocketServer
SEVERE: Fatal error starting http server.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.rpc.ServerRpcProvider.startWebSocketServer(ServerRpcProvider.java:328)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain.run(ServerMain.java:74)
    at org.waveprotocol.wave.examples.fedone.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:48)`

by default the server runs at the port 9898 as shown on the above output,I have tried using netstat and lsof to find what service is using that port but no one does!
also tried to change the port from the configuration but also no luck!
Has anyone had the same problem? if yes have he/she solved it? and how
also is there any linux command that I can query the port and tell me who is using that service?

Comment: ok found the way to search for a service given the port,terns out that the netstat way wasn't correct, you can query using this command:cat /etc/services | grep the-port-number-you-want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it terns out that the server runs after all but for some reason it complains about the bind exception.

The correct way to look for the service given a port is either the one on the comment above or using `fuser <protocol> <port>`.